# SharePoint: CAML query error when creating SPQuery query

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I have this CAML query

```
var query = new SPQuery
                                {
                                    Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
                                        <Or>
                                            <Or>
                                                <Or>
                                                    <Or>
                                                        <Contains>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='{7}' />
                                                            <Value Type='Text'>{3}</Value>
                                                        </Contains>
                                                    </Or>
                                                    <Contains>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='{6}' />
                                                        <Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value>
                                                    </Contains>
                                                </Or
                                                <Contains>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='{5}' />
                                                    <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
                                                </Contains>
                                            </Or>
                                            <Contains>
                                                <FieldRef Name='{4}' />
                                                <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                            </Contains>
                                        </Or>
                                    </Where>", "title", "adress", "zipcode", "city", "searchTitle", "searchAdress", "searchZipcode", "searchCity")
                                };
```

Every time it's ran and I try to use `List.GetItems(query);` it throws this error:

```
One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
```

BUT! If I remove all the `<Or>` tags it works and doesn't throw that error, but I need the `<Or>` tags to make sure it get all hits.

I've made sure all the fieldrefs matches the internal names of the columns 100%.

Comment: Dupe of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/caml-query-error-when-creating-spquery-query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your query without the  around the Contains 7/3 element? This one is imo not needed.

Also one of your /Or's has no closing bracket `<Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Contains></Or<Contains>`, this could be causing the error.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the result of the string.Format to the clipboard and run it in a tool like the U2U CAML Builder?

Comment: Have you tried removing all <or> statements and then simply adding them one at a time to see where it breaks?

Answer (score 0):

correct your CAML

```
    var query = new SPQuery
                            {
                                Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
                                        <Or>
                                            <Or>
                                                <Or>
                                                    <Contains>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='{7}' />
                                                        <Value Type='Text'>{3}</Value>
                                                    </Contains>
                                                    <Contains>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='{6}' />
                                                        <Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value>
                                                    </Contains>
                                                </Or>
                                                <Contains>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='{5}' />
                                                    <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
                                                </Contains>
                                            </Or>
                                            <Contains>
                                                <FieldRef Name='{4}' />
                                                <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                            </Contains>
                                        </Or>
                                </Where>", "title", "adress", "zipcode", "city", "searchTitle", "searchAdress", "searchZipcode", "searchCity")
                            };
```